# Splitting string with house number in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, regular-expression, address-parsing

I have a string field with housenumber which contains values like:

| housenumber |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 12 a |
| 15 b |
| 18 c |

What are the right expressions for the field calculator to write only the number in `"field1"` and only the string in `"field2"`:

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | NULL |
| 12 | a |
| 15 | b |
| 18 | c |

I guess regular expressions. But how to implement it?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this, but it's certainly possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extract information with a regular expression is always a bit tricky without having all the data, and can lead to unexpected results. For example what should happen if the field has data like `'a 22 a'`.

Taken that into account and with the sample data that you provide you can try with these two regular expressions.

```
# For field1
regexp_substr("hausnummer", '[0-9]*')

# For field2
regexp_substr("hausnummer", '[[:alpha:]]+')
```

[image]

BTW there is a [wonderful online tool](https://regex101.com/) that you can use to test regular expressions for different engines/languages

Answer (score 6):

- Find all *consecutive* **numbers** (first occurrences):

  ```
  regexp_substr( "hausnummer", '(\\d+)' )
  ```
- Find all *consecutive* **characters** (first occurrences, in range `a - z` & `A - Z`):

  ```
  regexp_substr( "hausnummer", '([a-zA-Z]+)' )
  ```

Comment: Thanks! The first expressions leads to a field with no values at all. But the second expressions works fine!

Comment: @EnzoBaldini ah, sorry, you need to escape with (double) ```\\```. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

f1 = `left("hausnummer",strpos("hausnummer",' ')-1)`

f2 = `right("hausnummer",length("hausnummer")-strpos("hausnummer",' '))`

Comment: Thanks! The first expressions works fine! But the second expression for f2 leads to the same result as the first...

Comment: A good try, but what to do if the house number is `22a` and not `22 a`?